# UIImage crashing issue

Tags: ios, image, swift, uiimage

I am having a crashing issue with images. Everything runs smooth if i enter an image from VC2 and click save sending it to a collection view in VC1.

However i have an image(png format) that i downloaded from google, and added to my xcode project which represents a placeholder for a person if the user doesn't actually select a picture while in VC2.

The issue is, in VC2 on my image View i set the image view to placeholderImage.png same for VC1 collectionView cell imageView.

Now while in VC2 if the user does not select an image and continues back to VC1 The image shows up as the placeholderImage.png because i added it that way in storyboard..

but when i exit the app or logout, then come back. My app crashes because i never actually set the image. The image comes back nil and it won't allow that.

**How can i set the image in VC1 collection view cell imageView to the placeholderImage.png file if there is no image selected in VC2??**

Thank you.

```
    import UIKit
    import Foundation
    import Parse

    class TrainerArray: NSObject, NSCoding,     UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

var name = ""
var trainerImage = UIImage()


func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encodeObject(name, forKey: "Name")
    aCoder.encodeObject(trainerImage, forKey: "TrainerImage")
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    name = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("Name") as! String
    trainerImage = (aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("TrainerImage") as! UIImage)
    super.init()
}

override init() {
    super.init()
}


}
```

Code for doneButton:

```
    //ADDING TRAINER
   } else if trainerPhoto.image != nil {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "To Add New Trainers", message: "Enter Username to continue", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { (textField) -> Void in
        }

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Add Trainer", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
            let textF = alert.textFields![0] as UITextField

            if textF.text! != PFUser.currentUser()?.username {
                self.displayAlert("Incorrect Username!", message: "Please enter a valid username")

            } else if textF.text! == PFUser.currentUser()?.username && self.trainerPhoto.image != nil {
                let item = TrainerArray()

                let trainer = PFObject(className: "Trainer")
                trainer["name"] = self.textField.text
                trainer["userWhoPosted"] = PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!

                let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.trainerPhoto.image!)
                let imageFile = PFFile(name: "image.png", data: imageData!)

                trainer["trainerImage"] = imageFile
                trainer.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success, error) -> Void in
                    if error == nil {
                        print("Successful save")
            }
            })
                item.name = self.textField.text!
                item.trainerImage = self.trainerPhoto.image!
                self.delegate?.addNewTrainerViewController(self, didFinishAddingItem: item)

            }



        }))

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
            if action == true {
                self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
            }}))

        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

Comment: Please show the relevant code and details of the crash

Comment: @Paulw11 `required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        name = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("Name") as! String
        trainerImage = (aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("TrainerImage") as! UIImage)
        super.init()
    }`

Comment: @Paulw11 seems to be crashing on this line(trainerImage =...) with error message: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: You should edit your question to show the code there; it is easier to read. Why are you decoding a string and an image from the storyboard? Also, you have omitted the call to super

Comment: @Paulw11 Decoding because i am saving these objects to the device, as well as parse. Updated code in Q

Comment: Ok, so this isn't a UIViewController subclass?  If there is a possibility that a value can legitimately be nil then don't use !.  Use ? and handle the the nil value appropriately

Comment: @Paulw11 i added these changes to that line `trainerImage = (aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("TrainerImage") as? UIImage)!` and it gave me a  EXC bad instruction crash.

Comment: You can't do that because `trainerImage` isn't optional. Either declare it as optional or provide an appropriate default if decodeObjectForKey returns nil. You need to think about the contract that your code makes and not just throw !s until it compiles

Comment: @Paulw11 I either need to allow image to be nil which i am unsure how to do... or, put a block on proceeding without adding a image to the image view in vc2 by pulling up an alert view asking to add a picture before continuing. I update my code again to show the code i have for the done button. Where may i add this?

Comment: Simply declare `trainerImage` as `var trainerImage:UIImage?`. Then it is an optional so it can be nil or add validation as you said

Comment: @Paulw11 i changed to `var trainerImage:UIImage?` and it gave me a bad instruction crash again, pointing to the line `trainerImage = (aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("TrainerImage") as! UIImage)`

Comment: Correct. You can't use ! If the value may be nil. Use ?  Have you read the Swift book from Apple?  Do you undertstand how optionals and unwrapping works?

Comment: @Paulw11 that worked, i no longer get the crash when logging in. However now if i do not add the image, the image remains as a blank white box. How can i set it to show `"placeholderImage.png"`

Comment: @Paulw11 i did, but then i dove head first into coding. i will definitely be re-reading it, ty for the suggestion

Comment: One way is to check if the decoder returns nil and if it does then use UIImage(named:) to get the default image. Look up the nil coalescing operator in the book.

Comment: Ok i will give it a go, Thank you!